# How do you do a crosstab query in Access with a fixed amount of columns

Tags: sql, ms-access, crosstab

I want to pull data with an MS Access crosstab query so I can bind it to a report. When I load the page I get a Run-time error'3637': Cannot use the crosstab of a non-fixed column as a subquery.

I would like a way to get back a fixed grid when I run the query and if the cell is null display a zero.

Comment: Here's an example. Depending on the dates in the filter it returns a different number of columns.

TRANSFORM Sum(tblCharting.Hours) AS SumOfHours
SELECT tblCharting.DateofService
FROM tblCharting RIGHT JOIN tlkpServiceLocations_SQL ON tblCharting.ServiceLocation = tlkpServiceLocations_SQL.ID
WHERE (((tblCharting.DateofService) Between #5/1/2009# And #5/5/2009#))
GROUP BY tblCharting.DateofService, tblCharting.DateofService
PIVOT tlkpServiceLocations_SQL.LocationName;

I'm looking to always return the same number of columns, which is the rows in the lookup table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subquery? That's one of my weaknesses when it comes to Access so I can't help you there.  I'd suggest posting the SQL of the query though so others can take a look.   Also what happens when you run the query?

The following is a query that I'm using to give me costs for the last ten years for a given unit.
TRANSFORM Sum(ServiceRecords.srTotalCost) AS AnnualCost
SELECT ServiceRecords.srEquipmentID
FROM ServiceRecords
GROUP BY ServiceRecords.srEquipmentID
PIVOT "C" & DateDiff("yyyy",[srServiceDate],Date()) In ("C9","C8","C7","C6","C5","C4","C3","C2","C1","C0");

The trick is after the PIVOT.  As I want the last ten years worth of data the "C" & DateDiff portion sets up a string variable call C0 to C9.  The portion after the In tells which column to stuff things into.

Another query which pulls in data about the Equipment calls this query.  The term we generally use for such is stacked queries.

If this isn't enough to get you going please indicate what type of data you are trying to create a cross tab.

Fellow Access MVP, Allen Browne has a good page on this topic.  [Crosstab query techniques](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-67.html)

Comment: Ok, I see what you're saying. Basically I can use the In ("x","y","z") with the desired column names. That works ok, but is there a way to have generate those from the rows of a lookup table automatically?

Comment: That's a great post. Thanks a lot.