# In MS Access how do you filter out the values in a column and add each in a new column?

Tags: database, ms-access

I think the best way i can explain this is with a example:  I have a table with Date, Location and Count as fields.  For each day is a record of counts for each location.  I want to reformat it with a query to filter each column by the location.

[image]

In MS Access in design view, I added the Date column and the Count column.  I set the criteria of the count column to [Count]="LA".  That gave me the counts for the LA column.  But when I added a second count column and set the criteria to [Count]="CH", the results came back with nothing. Nothing shows up for LA and CH.  Newbie here but how can i accomplish this?  I'd like to do this in reports as well once this query is successful.  Thanks.

Comment: Build a CROSSTAB query.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you do a crosstab query in Access with a fixed amount of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937797/how-do-you-do-a-crosstab-query-in-access-with-a-fixed-amount-of-columns)

Comment: @June7 Not sure if my question didnt come through clearly, but my intention is not to add up the counts for each location.  Rather i just want to shift things around format wise.  I checked an example of a crosstab, not sure if that is what I need. Perhaps I need to look at a few more examples.

Comment: Then use First or Max or Sum instead of Count in CROSSTAB. Alternative is to emulate CROSSTAB with expressions in a regular GROUP BY query.

Comment: Reason your criteria did not work is because you were essentially saying "get records where Count is equal to LA and CH" - no record can meet that criteria.

Comment: @June7 That worked thank you!  So in this scenario, I can't build the query with an ordinary select query by adding a column for each location like i had did it initially?  I understand your point that i was essentially saying count is equal to LA and CH, but is there another way of doing it where each column criteria is independent of each column criteria and build it out that way?  But regardless crosstab did the job. Thank you.

Comment: I already indicated there is alternative but it is actually more complicated than just doing CROSSTAB. It would use IIf() function in expressions along with GROUP BY clause.